# Getting model metadata from SageMaker model endpoint

Tags: tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker, h5py

I have a TF model object deployed to SageMaker endpoint, and it's working fine when I invoke it to make a prediction. On its own, the model object itself contains key attributes that is accessible if I open it with `h5py.File()` like this:

```
with h5py.File(model_path2, 'r') as f:
    labels = [n.decode("ascii", "ignore") for n in f['labels']]
    img_norm_vec = np.array(f['norm_vector'])
```

My question is, can I access the metadata attributes from a SM endpoint? I searched through the SM documentation and didn't see anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response. SM endpoint doesn't provide a way to extract model metadata attributes at this time. Following SDK doc link outlines the calls you can make against an Endpoint: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictors.html.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).